# Codeigniter login error switch between login and welcome

Tags: codeigniter, authentication

Now I'm developing system documentation using Codeigniter. But the problem is Not logged in Problems **switching** between pages. login and Welcome To switch on like this forever.

```
public function index()
{  
    if($this->input->post(NULL)){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $result = $this->m_login->check_login($username,$password);

        if(!empty($result)){
            $data_account = array();
            foreach($result as $row){
                $data_account = array(
                    'account_id' => $row->id,
                    'username' => $row->user_name,
                    'password' => $row->password,
                    'fullname' => $row->fullname,
                    'email' => $row->email,
                    'tel' => $row->tel,
                    'detail' => $row->detail
                );
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata('data_account',$data_account);
            $this->__login();
            //create_log_activity($this->account_id, date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
            redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
            exit;
        }else{
            $this->load->view('login');
        }
    }else if($this->session->userdata('data_account')){
        redirect('welcome', 'refresh');
        exit;
    }else{
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}

public function logout(){

    $this->session->unset_userdata('data_account');
    redirect('','refresh');
}
```

I want to know how to solve the problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you want to check `if($this->input->post('submit')){` instead of `if($this->input->post(NULL)){`?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
instead of
if($this->input->post(NULL)){